# Boto3: copy objects within bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Is it possible to copy/duplicate objects within one prefix to another prefix in the same s3 bucket?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`copy_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object) to copy an object in Amazon S3 to another prefix, another bucket and even another Region. The copying takes place entirely within S3, without needing to download/upload the object.

For example, to copy an object in `mybucket` from `folder1/foo.txt` to `folder2/foo.txt`, you could use:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3_client.copy_object(
    CopySource='/mybucket/folder1/foo.txt',  # /Bucket-name/path/filename
    Bucket='mybucket',                       # Destination bucket
    Key='folder2/foo.txt'                    # Destination path/filename
)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using boto3 `resource` instead of `client`:

```py
bucket = boto3.resource("s3").Bucket(my_bucket_name)
copy_source = {"Bucket": my_bucket_name, "Key": my_old_key}
bucket.copy(copy_source, my_new_key)
```

Where `my_bucket_name`, `my_old_key` and `my_new_key` are user defined variables.

Depending on the setup, additional arguments might be needed to instantiate a boto3 `resource`. A more complete instantiation call would be:

```py
boto3.resource(
        "s3",
        endpoint_url=my_endpoint_url,
        aws_access_key_id=my_aws_access_key_id,          # Do not expose me in source code!
        aws_secret_access_key=my_aws_secret_access_key,  # Do not expose me in source code!
    )
```